# Optimizing query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, query-optimization

I have created this query using MS Access:

```
SELECT
    Abonentai.vardas AS name,
    Abonentai.pavarde AS name1,
    Abonentai.email AS email,
    Abonentai.Telefonas AS phone1,
    Abonentai.[Gimimo metai] AS birthdate,
    "" AS phone2,
    "" AS name2,
    Last(Abonentai.Suma) AS paycost,
    Abonentai.vardas & " " & Abonentai.pavarde AS fullname,
    Last(AbonentaiD.Planas) AS Abonement_Code,
    Last(AbonentaiD.Nuo) AS Abonement_StartDate,
    Last(AbonentaiD.Iki) AS Abonement_ExpDate,
    Last(AbonentaiD.Kartai) - (SELECT COUNT(StatistikaID) FROM Statistika WHERE Statistika.AbonentasID = Abonentai.AbonentasID AND Statistika.AtvykimoData > (SELECT Last(AbonentaiD.Nuo) FROM AbonentaiD WHERE AbonentaiD.AbonentasID = Statistika.AbonentasID)) AS MAXQUANTVISIT,
    Abonentai.ANr AS CARDNO,
    "22" AS CARDTYPE,
    "" AS INFO
FROM Abonentai
    LEFT JOIN AbonentaiD ON Abonentai.AbonentasID = AbonentaiD.AbonentasID
WHERE 
    (((AbonentaiD.Iki)>Date())) AND (((AbonentaiD.Kartai) Is Null)) OR (((AbonentaiD.Kartai) Is Not Null) AND ((Abonentai.GaliojimoData)>Date()))
GROUP BY 
    Abonentai.vardas,
    Abonentai.pavarde,
    Abonentai.email,
    Abonentai.Telefonas,
    Abonentai.[Gimimo metai],
    Abonentai.vardas & " " & Abonentai.pavarde,
    Abonentai.ANr,
    Abonentai.AbonentasID,
    Abonentai.RegistracijosData
HAVING 
    Last(AbonentaiD.Kartai) - (SELECT COUNT(StatistikaID) FROM Statistika WHERE Statistika.AbonentasID = Abonentai.AbonentasID AND Statistika.AtvykimoData > (SELECT Last(AbonentaiD.Nuo) FROM AbonentaiD WHERE AbonentaiD.AbonentasID = Statistika.AbonentasID)) > 0
        OR
    Last(AbonentaiD.Kartai) - (SELECT COUNT(StatistikaID) FROM Statistika WHERE Statistika.AbonentasID = Abonentai.AbonentasID AND Statistika.AtvykimoData > (SELECT Last(AbonentaiD.Nuo) FROM AbonentaiD WHERE AbonentaiD.AbonentasID = Statistika.AbonentasID)) IS NULL
;
```

But it takes alot of time to excecute it. Is there any way to reduse excecution time? I need every vaue that I am selecting.

Comment: all those nested selects look like an issue. also the NULL and not NULL checks against those dates are probably killing your chances of using indexes...

Comment: What should I use besides that nested selects?